# Pyspark UDF - how to return multiple possible types?

Tags: pyspark

I'm learning how to use udf with Pyspark, but it seems from what I have seen that udfs can only have one return type. How do I create a UDF that returns one of a set of possible types?

e.g. for a function that returns either integers or strings, I'd want something like:

```
udf(my_func, IntegerType() or StringType())
```

Comment: This is not possible, though there might be workarounds. It depends on what you're trying to do. Can you try to provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)?

Comment: I'm trying to create a udf that catches certain exceptions for which it returns a string, but in normal cases returns an integer.

Comment: You can't do that because a column can't be of mixed type. You can return `null`, but a [mcve] would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done because columns cannot be of mixed type.